# Response data is undefine sended by XMLHttpRequest in node js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to save data in database at localhost using node js and XMLHttpRequest()
but at server side i can't find the sended data by XMLHttpRequest, It show me response.body is undefine.
i am using this code at client side to send data.

```
 var http = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
 http.open("POST","http://localhost:3000/saveorderdata",true);
     var body = {
             "orderID":"11111111",
             "price":"10900", 
             "Name":"xxxxxx",
             "date":"24-4-20"
            })
     http.send(body);
```

at server side my index.js file is this

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    port     : '3306',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'mypassword',
    database : 'mysql'
});

var app = express();

var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
} 

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/saveorderdata', function(request, response) {
    console.log("request "+request.orderID);
    var orderID = request.body.orderID;
    var price = request.body.price;
    var Name = request.body.Name;
    var date = request.body.date;
    
    console.log(orderID+" "+ price);
    if (orderID||true) {
          connection.query('insert into orderData (orderID, price, Name, date) values (?,?,?,?)', [orderID, price, Name, date], function(error, result, fields) {
        if(error) {
          
          console.log('error: '+ error);  
          response.send('Database error!');
          response.end();

        } else {

          response.send("data enter successfully ");
          response.end();   
        } 


      });   
    }
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('server running at - localhost:3000');
```

and NULL is saved in database insted of thoes values which i sent through XMLHttpRequest

Comment: You need to set the `Content-Type` header on the `XMLHttpRequest` object so that the server end point knows that you are sending `application/json` content

Comment: It looks like you are missing "//" in the protocol.
`http.open("POST","http://localhost:3000/saveorderdata",true);` and `http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");` should help you get further

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an object to [`send`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send), but that function doesn't accept a plain object, so it's going to get converted to a useless string.

You also said `app.use(bodyParser.json());` but:

- You aren't **saying** that you are POSTing JSON
- You **aren't** posting JSON

So:

```
http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
http.send(JSON.stringify(body));
```